# Error connecting database with sequelize, can somebody help me?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, crud

an "s" is added to it and it doesn't connect me because it can't find a table with that name (clearly because of the added letter), I'm not finding the reason in the code, I'm stuck there.

> Error: {   "message": "Table 'entornoP.chevents' doesn't exist" }
> console:Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `nombre`, `telefono`,
> `fecha`, `notas`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `chevents` AS
> `chevent`;

code:

```
import db from "../database/db.js";


import { DataTypes } from "sequelize";

    const BlogModel = db.define('chevent',{
        nombre: { type: DataTypes.STRING},
        telefono: { type: DataTypes.STRING},
        fecha: { type: DataTypes.STRING},
        notas: { type: DataTypes.STRING},
    })

export default BlogModel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Sequelize pluralizes table names from singular model names. You can change this behavior either on as concrete model level or globally in Sequelize options, see [table name inference](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#table-name-inference)

Example on the model level:

```js
 const BlogModel = db.define('chevent',{
        nombre: { type: DataTypes.STRING},
        telefono: { type: DataTypes.STRING},
        fecha: { type: DataTypes.STRING},
        notas: { type: DataTypes.STRING},
    }, {
  freezeTableName: true   
})
```